# Reactor subscriber not executed in the specified scheduler

Tags: java, couchbase, project-reactor

I'm starting with java reactor and facing an issue when testing a code that is querying couchbase and processing result documents.
My code looks like that

```
  Flux<String> documentIds = getDocumentIds();
  documentIds
        .windowTimeout(WINDOW, Duration.ofMillis(300))
        .onBackpressureBuffer()
        .flatMap(
            obs ->
                obs.concatMap(
                docId -> couchbaseCollection.reactive().get(docId, getOptions).retryWhen(retryFunction)),
            512)
        .takeWhile(d -> !interrupted.get())
        .map(
            doc -> processDocument(doc)
        .bufferTimeout(this.commitBatch,Duration.ofSeconds(11101))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(processorThread))
        .subscribe(
            new Subscriber<>() {
            
            }
```

I'm logging the methode onNext and can see it isn't executed in the thread specified in the subscribeOn methode, instead it is executed in couchbase KeyValue thread (cb-io-kv-x-y).

Which is more confusing is that if I change to use publishOn instead of subscribeOn, I get my code executed in the expected thread.
Any help please?

Answer (score 3):

SubscribeOn forces the source emission to use specific Schedulers, publishOn changes Schedulers for all the downstream operations in the pipeline.

https://www.vinsguru.com/reactor-schedulers-publishon-vs-subscribeon/

Answer (score 0):

That's correct.  The SDK uses its own thread pool ("cb-io") to execute operations on, and to avoid an expensive thread context switch (which would slow your application's performance), the SDK won't automatically switch back to your scheduler on returning control to you.

If you do need this, there's two options:

1. Use .publishOn() after each `collection.reactive().get()` to return to your scheduler.
2. Consider making the SDK use your scheduler instead of its own.  See "Computation scheduler" config option in [SDK client settings](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/ref/client-settings.html).